# Recursivity acces?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Alright then implement the objContains function: must search inside a nested object for a pair {key: value} specific. Both the object and the property name and its value will be received by parameter.
In the event that it finds the indicated value at any level of the object, it must return true, otherwise return false.

```
Ex:
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: 'homero@maxpower.com',
    Personal info: {
        name: 'Homer Simpson',
        address: {
            street: 'Avenue AlwaysLive',
            number: 742,
            neighborhood: 'Springfield',
            state: 'Massachusetts'
        }
    }
}
```

Case that returns true -> objContains (user, "neighborhood", "Springfield");

Case that returns false -> objContains (user, "employment", "Employee in nuclear plant");

Hint: use typeof to determine if the value of a property is an object to apply
there the recursion

this is what i've try

```
var objContains = function (obj, prop, value) {
   object var = prop.value
  if (typeof prop.value === obj) {
    var current = this.value;
    objContains (object, prop, current)
  } else if (this.prop === prop && prop.value === value) {
      return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```
AssertionError: expected false to equal true

      32 | }
      33 | it ('It should return true if it finds the property and its correct value', fun
ction () {
    > 34 | expect (objContains (user, "neighborhood", "Springfield")). to.equal (true);
      35 | });
      36 | it ('Should return false if the property is NOT found', function () {
      37 | expect (objContains (user, "employment", "Employee at nuclear power plant")). to.equal (
false);
```

Comment: What is the `object` part of `object var = prop.value` meant to mean (in the code)?

Comment: **All:** This looks like an assignment that we should *help* the OP with, **without** actually **doing it** for them.

Comment: its for helping me or maybe not idk what am reading right now xd too much hours trying it

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, `object var = prop.value` is a syntax error. That line isn't really doing anything for you, so you can just remove it. (Also, the solution to this assignment won't involve `this`.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

1. `typeof prop.value` checks the type of the property with the literal name `value` on whatever `prop` is. You've described `prop` as the *name* of an object property, so it doesn't make sense to try to look for `value` on it. You want to look on `obj`, not `prop`, [using the syntax described in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable). I don't think it's writing it for you to say that that looks like this: `if (obj[prop] === value)`
2. If you don't find the property with that value on `obj`, you should be looking through the other properties on `obj` and, if any of them refer to objects, calling your function with the object they refer to (and `prop` and `value`) and, if the function returns `true`, return `true`. Looping through the properties on the object is covered by [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object).

So the general form of a solution would be:

- See if `obj` has a property whose name is the *value* of `prop` that matches the value of `value`. If so, return `true`.
- If not, loop through `obj`'s other properties and check the type of their values; for each one that's an object (`typeof` is `"object"` and the value isn't `null`), call your function again with that property value, `prop`, and `value`. If it returns `true`, return `true`. If not, keep looping.

---

I'm purposefully just giving an indication of where to go, rather than writing the code, because this seems like an assignment we should **help** you with rather than doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I loop through each key in object...  if the the key refers to an object itself then recursively call... else check to see if that's the key we're looking for and if so check its value...   using the |= operator makes it easy to not worry about results of individual calls...  we just care if the conditions are true ANYWHERE in the tree..

```js
const user = {
  id: 6,
  email: 'homero@maxpower.com',
  "Personal info": {
    name: 'Homer Simpson',
    address: {
      street: 'Avenue AlwaysLive',
      number: 742,
      neighborhood: 'Springfield',
      state: 'Massachusetts'
    }
  }
}

var objContains = function(obj, prop, value) {
  var returnValue = false;
  var keyArray = Object.keys(obj);
  keyArray.forEach(property => {
    if (typeof(obj[property]) == 'object') {
      returnValue |= objContains(obj[property], prop, value);
    } else if (property == prop) {
      returnValue |= obj[property] == value;
    }
  });

  return !!returnValue;
}

console.log(objContains(user, 'neighborhood', 'Springfield'));
```